# How to import actual value, not formatted one from excel

Tags: excel, delphi, ado

I'm struggling with importing a date value from an excel file.
Importing part works fine! The only problem is its format.

In the excel file, all the date values are typed in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format but the cell itself displays it as 'dd-mm-yyyy'. When my program imports values from the excel file, it imports dates as 'dd-mm-yyyy' not the format users actually typed in 'yyyy-mm-dd'  - basically, formatted dates.

Well, I can manipulate 'dd-mm-yyyy' to 'yyyy-mm-dd' but would like to avoid this solution unless I really have no other ways to do it.

Is there any predefined delphi function to reverse 'dd-mm-yyyy' to 'yyyy-mm-dd'?
Or are there any special ways to bring the actual unformatted raw dates, not the formatted ones?

Unfortunately, changing cell format in excel is not an option here.. :'(

Thanks.

Update:::

```
  ConnectionString :='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;'+
                     'Data Source='+filename+';'+
                     'Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;'+
                     'Imex=2;HDR=NO;;';
   }
  // IMEX = 0: Export mode, 1: Import mode, 2: Linked mode (full update capabilities)
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  query := 'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]';
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(query);
  ADOQuery1.open;

  i:=0;
  while not eof do
  begin
    i:= i+1;
    Cells[0,i] := IntToStr(i);
    Cells[1,i] := Fields[1].AsString;
    Cells[2,i] := Fields[2].AsString;
    Cells[3,i] := Fields[3].Value; // This is the date value I'm trying to import.
    Cells[4,i] := Fields[4].AsString;
    Cells[5,i] := Fields[5].AsString;
    Cells[6,i] := Fields[6].AsString;
    Cells[7,i] := Fields[7].AsString;
    Cells[8,i] := Fields[8].AsString;
    Cells[9,i] := Fields[9].AsString;
    RowCount := RowCount+1;
    next;
  end;
```

Comment: Post the code you're using to "import the data from Excel", particularly the date cells. I have no issue doing this, and I have no problem reading raw date values. It's hard to say what the problem might be for you, because you've not provided any information yet.

Comment: @KenWhite I've updated it. Thank you :)

Comment: Would you mind if you post your sample code too? I'd like to compare if there are any differences.

Comment: @Raccoon Here on StackOverflow, users don't just post sample code so you can compare it with your own code. First of all, a comment doesn't have enough room to fit code like you posted in your question, second of all, it's inappropriate to post such sample code in an answer without it being an actual answer, and third of all this isn't that type of collaborative website. StackOverflow is not forums/threads.

Comment: @JerryDodge Thank you for your reply.  I've seen some people post their answers like 'This is how & what I did. Try it.'  So, I thought sharing some chunks of code was one way to share opinions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Field.Value`, which returns a `Variant` representation of the date as a `string` (because you're assigning it to a `string` in `Cells[]`), use it as a `TDateTime` and convert it to the format you want it in.

```
Cells[3,i] := DateToStr(Fields[3].AsDateTime);
```

or

```
Cells[3,i] := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', Fields[3].AsDateTime);
```

Based on your comments to my answer, it appears that the field doesn't actually contain a date, but contains a text value. In that case, you can try something like this:

```
try
  Cells[3, i] := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', VarToDateTime(Fields[3].Value));
except
  raise Exception.CreateFmt('Unable to convert %s to DateTime', 
    [Fields[3].Value]);
end;
```

Comment: That's what I tried already. However, it still seems like the problem is there.

Comment: Then you need to provide more information, because I use that same method frequently (as I mentioned before).

Comment: The cells in Excel are in custom format... :(   Literally, that's all the info I can give :'(

Comment: Everything else is explained above D:

Comment: If you access the data using `Field.AsFloat', what value is returned? The cell format should only affect the display of the data, not the content of it. (Unless the values are in fact not dates, but are text.)

Comment: It crashes saying '07-1-11' is not a valid floating point value

Comment: Then your cell isn't a date, it's text. I'll update my answer with another possibility.

Comment: StrToDate(VarToDateTime(Fields[3].Value)); Here, StrToDate takes a string parameter but VartoDateTime returns a Datetime value.

Comment: Fixed. Typed too fast - should be `FormatDateTime` instead. (You really should have been able to figure that out yourself.)

Comment: Awwwwwww... it still read dates as 'dd-mm-yyyy' and convert it to 'yyyy-mm-dd'.. but dd to yyyy and yyyy to dd... :(  Sigh...

Comment: Then you need to write code to parse it yourself. Since you said the cell format of the data can't be changed, you should be fine doing so.  It's really not that complicated; give me a couple of minutes, and I'll post yet a third suggestion.

Comment: Yup. I will just parse and manipulate them as string.  But I truly thank you for your support. Since the excel file I'm using is the biggest issue here, I will accept your answer in case other people may find the similar issue in the future.

Comment: Again, I truly appreciate :)

Comment: Oh, I can do the parsing part by myself :)  No worries.

Comment: Ok. :-) If you run into trouble, post a new question about the parsing and we can help. (Single and double digits can be an issue (`07-` and `7-`), and so can pre-century dates (eg., `07-1-99` should be `1999`, while `07-1-00` should be `2000`)).

Comment: Actually, I found another solution :D I counted how many days 'dd-mm-yyyy' has passed from 1900-1-1. With this result, I started adding this up to 1900-1-1 back again but in a correct format (yyyy-mm-dd) :D !!  This way, I don't have to worry about potential format changes in excel in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I've always solved this problem using automation after all the data has been written

```
 xlApp.Columns['C:C'].Select;
 xlApp.Selection.NumberFormat:=  'yyyy-mm-dd';
```

Incidentally, I recently made the *startling* discovery that it's much faster to write the values to a stringlist, save that stringlist as a csv file then import that csv file into Excel instead of assigning values to excel cells as you have done in your example. Csv files obviously don't allow any formatting but you can do that after the data has been imported into Excel.

(I write *startling* as this may turn out to be something which is well known - but I've never seen it documented). I wrote about it [here](http://www.nbnewman.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/speeding-up-excel.html).

Comment: The question was about *importing* Excel data, not exporting to Excel, and I'm pretty sure the `Cells[]` refers to a `TStringGrid`. Just as an FYI, though: It's much quicker to create a variant array and use that to add an entire range of cells to Excel; even considerably faster than using a CSV file. You should look into that (or post a question about doing it). You might be pleasantly surprised. :-)

Comment: I was startled as well. Variants are way too slooooow. My problem was trying to create two pages of a spreadsheet and I couldn't find a way to import the second csv file to a second sheet.